# Magento 2 Category Tree With Multiselect and Text box in Custom Page

Tags: magento2, category, model, resource-model

I am looking solution to get a Category tree on a custom page and parallel a text box, where the admin user could add some text and in parallel, he can select multiple categories. After adding text and selecting categories, there should be a save button so he can save this data in a custom table.

Please suggest how this can I do, I am not getting any solution for the category tree.

If anybody has an idea, please share me to implement it.

Comment: Working for you?

Comment: @RohanHapani , thanks for your effort, I am doing it as per your suggestion. Could you please let me know I want it only on a single page so will it work?

Comment: Yes it will work. Just add inside your *_listing.xml file

Comment: and also could you also please let me know how we save the values, there will be two fields one is text and another is multi-select categories, will it require to create the table or can we save in core_confog_data table?

Comment: It's depend on your requirement. You will get value in array after save. So, based on that you can save value.

Comment: @RohanHapani, I need just save in custom database table, so could you please add some steps on how to do it in your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117012/discussion-between-akgola-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this below code in your ui form XML file for add multi-select dropdown of category :

```
<!--
/**
 * Code standard by : RH
 */
-->
<field name="category_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\VendorName\Model\Source\CategoryTree</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Tree</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sourceName</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Then, Create **CategoryTree.php** file for set category tree options

> **app/code/Namespace/VendorName/Model/Source/CategoryTree.php**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\VendorName\Model\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as CategoryModel;

/**
 * Category Tree
 */
class CategoryTree implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $categoriesTree;

    /**
     * @param CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getCategoriesTree();
    }

    /**
     * Get categories tree
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        if ($this->categoriesTree === null) {
            $storeId = $this->request->getParam('store');
            /* @var $categoryCollectionFactory \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $categoryCollectionFactory = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $categoryCollectionFactory->addAttributeToSelect('path')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $shownCategoriesIds = [];

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
            foreach ($categoryCollectionFactory as $category) {
                foreach (explode('/', $category->getPath()) as $parentId) {
                    $shownCategoriesIds[$parentId] = 1;
                }
            }

            /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($shownCategoriesIds)])
                ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'is_active', 'parent_id'])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $categoryById = [
                CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID => [
                    'value' => CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID
                ],
            ];
            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                if ( $category->getData('level') <= 2 ) {
                    foreach ([$category->getId(), $category->getParentId()] as $categoryId) {
                        if ( !isset($categoryById[$categoryId]) ) {
                            $categoryById[$categoryId] = ['value' => $categoryId];
                        }
                    }
                    $categoryById[$category->getId()]['is_active'] = $category->getIsActive();
                    $categoryById[$category->getId()]['label'] = $category->getName();
                    $categoryById[$category->getParentId()]['optgroup'][] = &$categoryById[$category->getId()];
                }
            }
            $this->categoriesTree = $categoryById[CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID]['optgroup'];
        }

        return $this->categoriesTree;
    }
}
```

For more reference : [Click Here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-add-multi-select-ui-dropdown-in-ui-form-in-magento-2/)

Comment: getting error  "Call to a member function getData() on null", could you please check it.

Comment: thanks for your effort. Upvoted your answer. Could you please let me know How to display categories selected for single-row table?

Comment: Sorry? Not getting your point.

Comment: I am saving the values in custom table with comma separated. After saving these values I want to selected the categories in tree on the basis on these values.

Comment: could you please check my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/327671/24878